# Why does Vue not recognise the data member used in the v-html property?

Tags: vue.js

I have a reusable Vue component as follows:

```
Vue.component('ValueDisplay', {
    template: '<div v-html="value"></div>',
    data: function () {
        value: ''
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.$el.client = this;
    },
    methods: {
        SetValue: function(value) {
            this.value = value;
        },
    }
});
```

It is intended to be used as follows:

```
<value-display id="battery_percent">
```

Code that processes data from a web socket then calls the following function to set the value.

```
window.SetValue = function(name, value)
{
    var el = document.getElementById(name);

    if ((null != el) && el.hasOwnProperty('client')) {
        el.client.SetValue(value);
    }
}
```

This allows me to separate the display code and the web socket handling code as the web socket handling code is re-used for multiple HTML pages. I have used a similar pattern with a lot of success in my code, but this is failing.

The value is not being displayed and the web console is displaying the following error:

```
ReferenceError: value is not defined
```

Experimentation shows that this is because Vue thinks that there is no variable called "value" within the "data" part of the component.

Elsewhere I have another Vue component that is more complex. It has multiple values that are used, and updated, in a similar fashion. It works fine.

```
Vue.component('NavPane', {
    template: `<table class="fixed">
...
                         <td v-html="speed"></td>
...
    data: function () {
        return {
...
            speed: ''
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
    },
    methods: {
    }
});
```

When you boil it down, this code is doing exactly the same thing as the failing code, but this component works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a small mistake here:

```js
data: function () {
  value: ''
},
```

You've merged the braces from a function declaration and an object literal. It should be something like this:

```js
data: function () {
  return {
    value: ''
  }
},
```

Comment: Well spotted. I couldn't see the wood for the trees, so many different levels of scoping in javascript!
It appears I cannot accept for another 6 minutes.
Thankyou! You have saved me hours!